# Is there a consensus among cosmologists about the big freeze or any “fate of the universe” scenario?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

Any insight into the matter would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there theories about the end of the universe where time ends?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/593528/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is called the $\Lambda$CDM scenario. It is based on current data. It predicts that the universe will expand forever, at an accelerated pace, and continue to cool while doing so: the Big Freeze.

Answer (score 0):

One small error in your answer. The diagram in
[Are there theories about the end of the universe where time ends?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/593528/are-there-theories-about-the-end-of-the-universe-where-time-ends)
shows that for Omega_m = 0.3 and Omega_Lambda = 0.7 (the only curve satisfying the sum of Omegas equal "1") the acceleration curve becomes closer and closer to a straight line as time passes. Thus it will not have "an accelerated pace".